# Best practice for getting a resource in many different ways?

Tags: api-design

An example of this problem:

I'm writing a function allowing a user to find a student by their studentId, so I create the function:
`GetStudent(int id)` or `GetStudentById(int id)`

Then the users want to get a student by SSN, so I create a function `GetStudent(string ssn)` or `GetStudentBySSN(string ssn)`

Then more requirements expose `GetStudent(string first, string last)` and `GetStudent(string phoneNumber)`

These aren't particularly good examples because first/last might not be unique, but let's say for the sake of argument you just want to return the first relevant student.

The result of all this is a bloated API.

An Alternative I've heard discussed:
1. GetStudent(Dictionary searchCriteria), where the key is something like "id", "ssn", etc and the value is the corresponding id or ssn. The implementation would then do the parsing of the dictionary and use the search criteria passed in. This seems less intuitive to use and someone would have to look at the docs to see the options (not the end of the world).

So what's the best practice here? Is there a third (better) option? Does it change if you're building a web api instead of a library? Restful seems like it would be /student/{id} for getting by id, and I'm not sure what comes after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The result of all this is a bloated API.

Do you know reasonably who will be consuming the API and the data it produces? (At least initially. These things always change over time.) If so, ask them what they want.

Then also consider what data is available when. It could be that some data is not always accessible at all times. For example, if there are fields that are calculated rather than stored directly, you won't be able to access them until they've been calculated. That may affect whether you want to easily make all fields available at all times.

I would strongly suggest against the approach of having the caller supply a dictionary of key-value pairs for the data they want. There is significant pain down that road for both you and a consumer of the API. Things that can't be caught by compilers like misspellings of keys, invalid keys, keys that are no longer supported, etc. It makes it hard to use the API, hard to debug the API for you, and hard to deprecate things in the future and change the API.

Answer (score 1):

I would first examine your specific requirements before deciding on a course of action.  How you design your API is going to depend a great deal on what those requirements are.  For instance, are your users sophisticated enough to deal with a more general API having fewer methods?

One of  the reasons why you might want multiple methods is that it can provide you with precise control over your  API.  A method like

```
FindStudent(string fieldName, string searchTerm);
```

must be carefully designed to avoid abuse, along the lines of SQL injection or accessing a field that the user doesn't have rights to.  Specific methods that are very limited in their purpose are easier control, because you have fewer possible abuse scenarios to deal with.